# Microsoft.AspNet.Identity MVC how to configure the system to automatically login with token but no password

Tags: authentication, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, token, autologin

I'm new to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity. I have a url-token:

> http://example.org/news/titlenew?userId=0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e&token=abcxyzabczyieeieusjhjsyuwhjihsihywsuyhskuju

In my database there is user information but no password.

I want that: when I send this url-token to someone, and when they click on it will come to my page, the system will automatically get the token from the url, authenticate it with the user in the database.

If valid then Automatically login to my system, otherwise go to the login page.

I think it will need to configure something at startup.auth or IdentityConfig, but I do not know how it is. Please guide me because I'm new to Identity.

Comment: What good is the login page if the user has no password?

Comment: Why don't you use the regular Register flow from identity? Register a user, send a link to activate to the user. User clicks the link to activate and login.

Comment: Please understand that this is just a guest. Not a member. And I wanted to show them a page when they invited me to the event.

Comment: So you just want to show a page to a specific person that is not a member in your system, with other words, there is no user record for this person?

Comment: Yes, I want to show to a guest, but this guest has been saved to my database, this guest has no account to log in with only userid and email. I created a token from uid.
I'm looking for something like identity external login by token, it checks if the token validates to my site without logging in.
Sorry i'm not good at english

Comment: The token you mention, how is that created? Is it some self generated value, or does it mean something?

Comment: I use UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what you are suggesting is to login using a url. You use a token that never changes nor expires. It isn't secure. Anyone who knows the url can access the resource as long as the user exists. So basically you are bypassing the purpose of AspNet Identity: to identify the user.

You certainly do not want to sign in users based on just this url and risking to expose more than you may want.

If you look at the Register flow, you'll see that you can send an email verification code. But you'll also see that the *ConfirmEmail* method has the attribute 'AllowAnonymous' and that the user isn't logged in afterwards. It is just to verify the email.

You'll need to identify the user first, before you authorize the user. You can use credentials (local login) or you can use an external id provider like Google or Facebook.

You can also implement something where you send a code (one time password) to the email after the link was clicked, so the user has to enter this code before signing in.

But if you just want to show one page, which doesn't contain sensitive information (just a personal message), then you do not need to sign in the user. You can create your *TitleNew* method (add the 'AllowAnonymous' attribute), examine the code in the url (like in ConfirmEmail) and show the page with the personal message, based on the userid from the url.

Comment: I think I will only allow tokens to work for a certain period of time.
What you say is true, I like it.